# Paypal not converting currency when using Gravity Forms on WordPress

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, paypal

I have a WPMU setup, and one particular network site is using Gravity Forms and Gravity Forms PayPal Standard Add-On. All Gravity Forms are set to use South African Rand as the currency.

When the form is submitted to PayPal, I can see the query string includes currency_code=ZAR, however, on the PayPal payments page, the amount is displayed in USD using a 1:1 conversion/exchange rate. So, a product for ZAR1,000.00 is charged as USD1,000.00.

What's going wrong here? Is there a setting I've missed somewhere?

Comment: Is the Paypal account set up for ZAR?

Comment: PayPal does not accept ZAR, therefore amounts need to be converted to a currency PayPal does accept (I've chose USD). I've previously successfully set up eCommerce using ZAR and PayPal + WooCommerce. It's just not working with PayPal and Gravity Forms this time.